# Can you access a global javascript variable in an Angular expression?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

Is there a way to access a global JavaScript variable in a Angular expression? such as:

```
ng-disabled="{someJavascriptVariableHere}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular expressions will look only for variables on the $scope, but if you do something like this in your controller:

```
// assumes someJavascriptVariableHere exists in the global scope
$scope.someJavascriptVariableHere = someJavascriptVariableHere;
```

then you can access it.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I wanted to add that the reason you can access a global variable directly inside of an angular expression is because the angular expression is being evaluated in the context of the scope and if the scope or it's parent scopes don't know the global variable then it will implicitly create the variable.